# is that fine to install ubuntu 20.04 LTS amd in intel?

Tags: system-installation, data-recovery, intel, format, amd-processor

i have window 10 64 bit intel processor. and i want to install ubnutu 20.04 LTS amd 64 bit processor. will it create any problem in the performance of the PC?

Answer (score 5):

If you're referring to the "amd64" in the ISO file name (`ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso`), this means the CPU architecture of your CPU. Modern AMD and Intel CPUs all support the amd64 architecture. There are other architectures, but they're niche, and you would probably know if you had a CPU with one of those niche architectures because you would have bought the CPU with a particular goal in mind. Most CPUs that people buy for workstations, gaming PCs, etc., use amd64 architecture.

Answer (score 2):

A long time ago AMD came out with 64 bit CPUs.  Intel came out with them after.  Ubuntu tagged the new versions as amd64 and has not changed since then, even when Intel had 64 bit CPUs also.  AMD64 is for amd and intel CPUs.